# "Guts" Meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

A doctor cured his patient and operated upon him well. Actually the patient was shot at his lower back, he had escaped from a jail and the doctor took the bullet out of his body. The patient was unconscious, he was in pain and when the doctor took the bullet out, patient said

> "Guts".

He was choking, then he told

> "They got......my guts..."

"Guts" here is actually creating a lot of commotion for me. Can someone please clear?

Is it like: "Internal organs of his body". When the bullet was taken out, he felt like his internal organs are being removed. (Guts = Internal organs). OR something else?

[Guts](https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=2oqHWuqKCIXZvgSJyb3AAg&q=guts%20meaning&oq=guts%20mea&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39k1j0l9.87332.88302.0.89307.4.4.0.0.0.0.248.248.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.1.247....0.iAyRkbRziK0) meaning here.

Comment: He was shot in the guts, or stomach. Since he was shot, he couldn't formulate full sentences properly.

Comment: [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/get) **get** verb transitive ... 13 ... g. Informal To hit or strike: She got him on the chin. The bullet got him in the arm.

Comment: Guts are the entrails, the intestines - all thirty five feet of it, or whatever - plus the various organs that fall out (spleen, liver etc etc) when the entrails are removed. It's a pretty big target and anywhere in there is serious. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=guts+entrails&oq=guts+entrails&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.3090j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gut/guts - the stomach, belly or abdominal area.  [As defined by Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=def%20-%20guts&rlz=1C1CHJW_enUS469US469&oq=def%20-%20guts&aqs=chrome..69i57.5719j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> **"They got me in my gut[s]"**

Comment: How perfect you are in explaining everything concisely. I actually now want you to let me complete the full class 12 chapter that I have to read by myself because I have no teacher.